# What type of cable do I need to connect to this storage box

Tags: networking, network-adapter, storage, cable

I have this Hitachi Storage box ([Hitachi DF600-RKAJAT Hard Drive Array](http://quickreference.weebly.com/uploads/1/5/4/2/15423822/ams-wms_parts_catalog.pdf)):

[image]

It has fiber drives, and I have a Fiber channel card like this:

[image]

How can I join them?

Comment: you can not tell us the exact model number for the storage device?

Comment: @Logman http://cgi.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=221311253245&ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:AU:1123

Comment: fiber drives? the drives are internal sata probably. Is this a DAS array? You put the card in your server and attach the storage device to it.

Comment: @Logman , sorry u r right, i put sata drives inside that and i have put card in server. but i don't know which cable i need to connect card with HItachi things. hitachi has in and out port and FC card also has two ports. they both look different ports don't know how to join them

Comment: This is enterprise hardware, which is off-topic for Super User. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but your card is fibre optic, and your chassis is electrical.

So-called "Fibre Channel" actually has variants that don't use fibre optic cables at all, and instead uses purely electrical (over copper wiring) connections. It looks like your drive chassis is one of those. It looks like it uses HSSDC connectors, which are electrical, not fibre optic.

Some Fibre Channel devices use GBIC or SFP (mini-GBIC) slots so you can choose which type of fiber or electrical transceiver to use. But unfortunately, it looks like your card and your chassis both have fixed connectors instead of GBIC or SFP slots, so you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks spiff for that info, now what type of card i need to connect chasis to my server. is there something like HSSDC card available for PCI-E slot. becaus ei want to use that storage server